# How to Pass Java code into selenium node from grid

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium RC.
i need to pass file upload java code into selenium node for execution from grid, is it possible?

I've this following file upload code which, i am calling from selenium code:

```
package com.wipro.Base.Base20.QA.SeleniumTests.FullRegression;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * @author Bogdan Gusiev
 *         Date 29.03.2009
 */
public class FileChooserThread extends Thread {`

    public FileChooserThread(String file) {
        super(new FileRunner(file));
    }
}

class FileRunner implements Runnable {

    private String fullName;

    public FileRunner(String fileName) {
        this.fullName = fileName;
//        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Robot robot = new Robot(); //input simulation class
            for (char c : fullName.toCharArray()) {
                if (c == ':') {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                } else if (c == '/') {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
                } else {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                                   Character.toUpperCase(c), 0).getKeyCode());
                }
            }
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}`
```

`//Here is selenium call method:

```
protected void chooseFile(String element, String fileName) { 

Number   positionLeft = selenium.getElementPositionLeft(element); 

Number positionTop =   selenium.getElementPositionTop(element);

new FileChooserThread(fileName).start(); //launch input thread. 

//this   method will held current thread while FileChooser gives the file name 

selenium.clickAt("file", positionLeft + ","+ positionTop); 

}`
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please indent code by four spaces to make it easy to read. Also don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Is there any other way to UpLoad file Using **Selenium RC** and Run it in **Grid**

Comment: I don't know any. My instinct would be to move to Selenium WebDriver; things like the above are more simple there. But I don't know if Grid is supported with Selenium WebDriver.